# Refining LSTM using Deeplearning4j UI

Tags: deeplearning4j

I am getting into Deeplearning4j and am at a stage where I need to refine my LSTM training but have run into a flew blockers.

So far I have based my work on various time-series prediction examples in Deeplearning4j. I am able to train an LSTM using a DataSet and predict future steps with some degree of accuracy but am unsure how to ensure my configurations are correct i.e. that I am not over-fitting my data.

I have been using the Deeplearing4j UI to help understand the training process but I am a bit confused by some of the metrics. I was wondering if anyone could clarify what the difference between the **Summary** and **Score** lines represent in the chart on the top left hard corner of the overview page? I have provided an image of this below. Do these correlate to training and validation errors which would identify over-fitting / under-fitting of data?

[image: Model Score vs. Iteration]

If not, what is the best way to extract this information and diagnose any issues with my LSTM? I have seen uses of the Evaluation class but am unsure if this is already done by the ui plugin? Furthermore, if the Evaluation class is required, is there any way to integrate this into the UI plugin so it is easily displayed?

I am also using a DataSet instead of a DataSetIterator which may cause issues when using the Evaluator class as I can't see a way to evaluate the net using a plain DataSet.

My final question is a bit more of a general time-series training one. I understand to achieve useful evaluation of my net, a split of the training data is used. For example, 70% is used for training and 30% for evaluation. In the case of time-series data, could this be problematic? If not all data is used in the training process, it could mean the LSTM does not learn the most recent and relevant trends which allow it to do its job well. How is this normally solved when using Depplearing4j for time-series prediction?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!